# Outlook New Message - Text Area Below Toolbar

Tags: office-interop

I am creating an addin for Outlook.

I want to check some text on sending, but im not sure how to reference it

The text is in the image below and says “Attachment will be sent using...”

If the text equals the text displayed, i want to do something.

Thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for reading mail tips. But you may consider using [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for getting mail tips. See [Using MailTips in EWS to get the OOF (Out of Office) Status of users with C# and Powershell](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.by/2011/11/using-mailtips-in-ews-to-get-oof-out-of.html) for the sample code.

FYI *MailTips* are informative messages displayed to users in the infobar in Outlook Web App and Outlook 2010/2013/2016 when a user does any of the following while composing an e-mail message:

- Add a recipient
- Add an attachment
- Reply or Reply all
- Open a message from the Drafts folder that's already addressed to recipients

To configure MailTips for mailboxes, external contacts, and distribution groups, in the Exchange Control Panel, select the mailbox, external contact, or distribution group, click Details, and then in the MailTip section, create the MailTip.

To configure MailTips for mail users and dynamic distribution groups, in Windows PowerShell, use the MailTip parameter on the Set-MailUser and Set-DynamicDistributionGroup cmdlets.

Regardless of whether you use the Exchange Control Panel or Windows PowerShell, two things always happen when you add a MailTip to a recipient:

- HTML tags are automatically added to the text. For example, if you enter the following text: `This mailbox is not monitored.` The MailTip automatically becomes the following: `<html><body>This mailbox is not monitored.</body></html>`
- The text is automatically added to the `MailTipTranslations` property as the default value. If you modify the MailTip text, the default value is automatically updated in the `MailTipTranslations` property.

Read more about that in the [Configure MailTips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff872400%28v=exchsrvcs.149%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Custom) article.